How to evaluate Trained detector on test dataset in Matlab?
How can I evaluate Trained detector on test dataset, pelase? Here example code:
tic
detectionResults = detect(Trained_detector, testData, 'MiniBatchSize', 50);
% Evaluate the object detector using average precision metric.
[ap,recall,precision] = evaluateDetectionPrecision(detectionResults, testData);
classID = 1;
figure
plot(recall{classID},precision{classID},'LineWidth',4)
xlabel("recall")
ylabel("accuracy")
grid on
title(sprintf("AP = %.3f",ap(classID)))
toc

Here Error:
*Expected I to be one of these types:
double, single, int16, uint16, uint8, logical
Instead its type was matlab.io.datastore.CombinedDatastore.*


Test data is expected to be a single image or, for some detectors, an array of images, not a datastore. See doc detect.
